# Cannot find module .... ts(2307)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Although the pictures are there and they load when I start the project. Why vscode can't recognise the path.

I tried many solution out there like setting typescript work directory, include tag in tsconfig.json etc.

[image: code snippet]

Comment: Can you provide tsconfig.json file?

Comment: `{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES2018",
  "module": "CommonJS",
  "lib": [
   "dom",
   "esnext"
  ],
  "declaration": true,
  "declarationMap": true,
  "noEmit": true,
  "jsx": "react",
  "strict": true,
  "pretty": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "noUnusedParameters": true,
  "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "allowJs": true
 },
 "include": [
  "./src/**/*.ts",
  "./src/**/*.tsx",
 ], 
}`